# String Argument vs. Template Parameter for Formatting

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

I'm wondering if one of these two methods for supplying a format string could be considered "more correct". Obviously both work, but one requires a series of constant strings to be maintained in a namespace, while the other uses a class:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

// Method 1: constant strings:
char const* STANDARD = "%c";
char const* ISO8601  = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z";

const std::string timestamp(char const* format) {
  time_t raw_time;
  time(&raw_time);
  struct tm* time_info = localtime(&raw_time);
  const size_t maxsize = 80;
  char time_str[maxsize];
  strftime(time_str, maxsize, format, time_info);
  return time_str;
}

// Method 2: Class-based formatter used as a template parameter:
struct standard {
  static inline char const* format() { return "%c"; }
};

struct iso8601 {
  static inline char const* format() { return "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"; }
};

// The formatter is supplied as a template parameter.
template<typename T>
const std::string timestamp() {
  time_t raw_time;
  time(&raw_time);
  struct tm* time_info = localtime(&raw_time);
  const size_t maxsize = 80;
  char time_str[maxsize];
  strftime(time_str, maxsize, T::format(), time_info);
  return time_str;
}

int main() {
  // Method 1: constant strings:
  std::cout << timestamp(ISO8601) << std::endl;

  // Method 2: template:
  std::cout << timestamp<iso8601>() << std::endl;
}
```

Thoughts? Suggestion? I'm not as familiar with template programming (traits, strategies, etc.) as I could be, so I'm really curious is one of these is "better" or "more correct" than the other.

Comment: You need to either use `timestamp<ISO8601>()`,   or add a parameter to allow the compiler to deduce the type.

Comment: [`put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) would be "better" since it is in the standard already (C++11).

Comment: @Photon Why? `timestamp( char const* )` isn't a template.

Comment: The first implementation of `timestamp` accepts a string parameter to the function that defines the output format. The second implementation accepts a template parameter for the same purpose, which is more of a "policy based design"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're naming the different formats, and you want a constant name at
all of the call sites, then the obvious solution is something like:

```
extern char standard[] = "%c";
extern char iso8601[] = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z";

//  ...

template <char const* format>
std::string timestamp()
{
    //  ...
}
```

If there aren't too many named formats, you might even use explicit
specialization:

```
template <char const* format> std::string timestamp();
template<> std::string timestamp<standard>()
{
    //  ...
}
template <> std::string timestamp<iso8601>()
{
    //  ...
}
```

If you're evaluating the format dynamically, however, I don't see where
these buy you much over `std::string timestamp( char const* format )`.
About the only advantage in using templates is that the solution with
explicit instantiations ensures that you will never get anything but one
of the known formats; the code will fail to compile and link if you
don't have an explicit instantiation.  This in turn means that you don't
need any additional checks that your buffer is large enough (which you
omit anyway—in both of your implementations, it's possible for a
user to give an artificial string which will result in buffer overflow).

Comment: Interesting explanation... Am I wrong about my second example being  policy-based design, or is it simply over-complicated for the task at hand?

Comment: @Paul I suspect that it depends on how you define policy-based design.  I would tend to say it's not, because the actual implementation doesn't change, but the semantics do.  On the other hand, if you explicitly limit the formats, by only providing specialized versions of the function, it's definitely a pattern which needs a name, and I don't have one off hand.

Comment: Cool! I wish I could accept this comment as the answer. I'll accept the answer you provided and upvote the comment. If you do happen to think of a name for the pattern, feel free to drop it in here. Thanks again!